# Javascript does not print the name of the button received from php?

Tags: javascript, php

The below given php code generates button based on different names received from the database. I am then using the PostUpdate(this) javascript method to get the value i.e the name of the button but it prints as blank ? I am expecting an output like for eg the name is button 1 it should alert button 1.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      $message = $row['Timings'];

      $message = substr($message, 0, -2).":".substr($message, -2);
      echo "<button class=\"ui-btn ui-btn-b\" onclick=\"PostUpdate(this);\" >" . $message . "</button>";
      }

}
```

.

```
function PostUpdate(str)
{
   alert("Called a Button");
   alert(str.value);          
}
```

Comment: Try with: `alert(str.innerHTML);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value being passed into your `PostUpdate` is not a string, it's a DOM element.

If you want that element's contents, you can use `innerHTML` to get them as a string:

```
function PostUpdate(button)
{
    alert("Called a Button");
    alert(button.innerHTML);
}
```

If you want the *value*, you can use `value`, but note that your `button` doesn't *have* a value (more accurately, its value is `""`). You can give it a (different) value by specifying a `value` attribute for it, e.g., adding `value="the value"` in the opening `<button>` tag.